# Remove tag in magit

Tags: git, emacs24, magit

I would like to remove a tag from a previous commit and I cannot find a way to do this in magit (I am using emacs24). I realize that I could probably use ":" and then enter the git command but I was wondering whether there might be a magit-specific way.

Comment: I just found [this hack](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/629). But maybe something like that has been meanwhile included in magit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`magit-delete-tag` will do it (run by `M-x magit-delete-tag`). With recent version of magit, <kbd>t k</kbd> will run it.